# Virtualization enabled but not being displayed windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

I have enabled virtualization in my BIOS settings. However, it is disabled when I check it in my Task Manager.

[image: Task Manager.]

I need to run **docker** in windows. 
When I try to run Docker, the following error pops up.

[image: docker.]

I have also enabled Hyper-V as follows:

[image: hyper-v.]

I have tried both enabling and disabling Hyper-V before enabling virtualization.
However, none of this seems to solve the problem of virtualization being disabled.

When I run this after disabling hyper-v, I get an error:

```
cannot open vmms service on computer '.'.
If you just enabled Hyper-V, please restart now.
```

Comment: Are vmms and vmcompute services running? You could try to enable Hyper-V features from Powershell. Don't know if that'll help though. Can you see what's the error code from Event viewer? Should you have the Hyper-V Hypervisor feature enabled?

Comment: Your last screenshot clear shows Hyper-V is NOT installed.  **Hyper-V Hypervisor** is gray and not installed. Make sure Core Isolation isn’t enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Hyper-V Hypervisor feature, which according to your screenshot is disabled and grayed out. Docker might require you to reboot before starting it. Make sure your services are running correctly.